# How to use the clipboard in Go?

Tags: go, clipboard

How can I copy to the clipboard, or get data from it, using Go?

I'm a bit concerned that there are [no results in the documentation](http://golang.org/search?q=clipboard) and [Google has yielded me this result](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/-ptPFfL3a6o/9NzqhPIRiY4J), but I want this to work cross-platform... then I found [this playground snippet](http://play.golang.org/p/ekKyppCEEC) (from that page) but it doesn't compile (because the "unsafe" package can't be used in the playground, I get this, but it still looks platform-dependent).

So is this even possible, cross-platform?

Comment: Do you mean the Windows clipboard?

Comment: @theglauber Cross-platform.

Comment: I don't think that exists. It would have to be provided by the underlying runtime, and there is no common runtime between Go and other no-Go applications. The example you saw, uses Windows' [user32.dll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files#USER32.DLL)

Comment: It doesn't mean it can't be done, but it would require platform-aware code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to os.exec(..) out to the platform-specific command for copying-to/pasting-from the clipboard.

Or you could use platform-specific libraries to do this, but I'm pretty sure there's no platform agnostic way to access the clipboard.

Answer (score 3):

Clipboard is a platform-specific thing, so you should use a third party package.
For example, use go-gtk.

https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/tree/master/_example/clipboard

This will work on platforms which are supported by GTK.