# How to get clipboard information (copy & paste) in Go

Tags: go, clipboard, copy-paste

Is there a way to get the information that is saved in clipboard (copy & paste) in Go?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the clipboard in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178617/how-to-use-the-clipboard-in-go)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy text to / from clipboard in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21340920/10197418)

Answer (score 6):

Since I'm not sure what OS you're on, I'll just recommend a library supporting the tree major ones.

https://github.com/atotto/clipboard

Answer (score 0):

Another multi-platform library that allows you to set/get text to/from the clipboard.
https://github.com/F1bonacc1/glippy

The advantage of glippy is that it doesn't require installation of additional packages in Linux ('xclip' or 'xsel').